# jQuery Adding in <tr> elements after other <tr> elements

Tags: jquery, slice, tablerow

Am trying to add in `<tr>` elements after other `<tr>` elements in the table according to the rowspan of a `<td>` element within that specific `<tr>` element.  Within the same function, upon clicking this button within the `<td>` element, the rowspan is increased by 1 each time, so it needs to increase the number of rows also.  Not sure how to do this.  Perhaps using `slice()` function somehow.

For example, say we have this table structure.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 1</td>
    <td>Content 2</td>
    <td>Content 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Content 4</td>
    <td colspan="2">Content 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content 6</td>
    <td>Content 7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So I want to be able to click a button within the `<td rowspan="2">Content 4</td>` element and create another `<tr>`, but because the rowspan already equals 2, I need another `<tr>` element to appear at the end of the table, cause it needs to count the current parent `<tr>` element as 1 in the list of `<tr>` children of the `<table>` element and the next `<tr>` element after that should be counted as 2, so it needs to add in a `<tr>` element at the end cause there are 2 rowspans in `<td rowspan="2">Content 4</td>`.

So basically, I need to capture all children `<tr>` elements starting with the parent `<tr>` element and increment down the `<tr>` element list within the `<table>` and count them with the `rowspan`, if `rowspan=1` or rowspan does not exist, than it should create another `<tr>` element directly after the parent `<tr>` element of the `<td>` element...

```
$(this).parent().after('<tr></tr>');
```

But I'm thinking that I can't use `after()` here, and should use `slice()` somehow, cause if the rowspan equals 2, than it needs to skip 2 `<tr>` elements, including the parent `<tr>` element, and add it after that.  It needs to be totally based on the rowspan of that `<td>` element that is clicked so that the new `<tr>` elements will always be placed in the proper order.

An example of the code I'm actually using to accomplish the `after()` part, that needs to be changed based on the rowspan instead, is as follows:

```
for (var i = 0, len = maxAddSections; i < len; i++)
{
    tdHtml += '<td class="dp_add_section" colspan="1" style="display: table-cell;"><div style="opacity: 0.6;"><span class="upperframe"><span></span></span><div class="roundframe blockframe" style="text-align: center;">ADD SECTION</div><span class="lowerframe"><span></span></span></div></td>';
}
pTd.parent().after('<tr class="dp_add_tr_section">' + tdHtml + '</tr>');
```

`pTd` is the actual `<td>` object that is being clicked on, inside of the `<td>` element.  So, I can grab the rowspan as follows:
`pTd.attr('rowspan');`
but how can I put it where it needs to go?  Like is there a `nextAll` and calculate it based on the rowspan, but only add in the `<tr>` element 1 time?

BTW, I'm using `maxAddSections` that tells me how many `<td>` elements to add.

I need to change `pTd.parent().after(... code ...);` to add it after the rowspans from `pTd.parent()` which is a `<tr>` element and needs to count the number of rowspans and skip that many `<tr>` elements including the one that it is in.  And that's where it needs to add in the new `<tr>` element: `'<tr class="dp_add_tr_section">' + tdHtml + '</tr>'`

So, hopefully, this helps to clarify what I'm trying to do better.

How can I do this?

Comment: description of rules is confusing... talk about parent tr and child tr but there are no nested tr's. An example of "after" markup would help

Comment: Is it safe to assume I'm reading this as "How do I add rows to a table, taking in to account any row/colspans?"

Comment: @ charlietfl, added in more code to help you understand how I'm currently using the `after()` jQuery function, which needs to be changed.  So hopefully you have a better understanding now.  @Brad, I already take into account, the colspans, just need to take into account the rowspans, but yeah, that's basically a better way of putting it.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST: I guess I'm a little confused; would you have instances where `rowspan` would have a value greater than the remaining number of rows in the table? i.e. you'd still have another row that would fall beneath it, then it could go back to a normal column count? (Basically, sticking with your top example, make it `rowspan="4"`, which would be two more rows of 3 columns, then a row of 4)

Comment: @Brad:  No, rowspan will never have a value greater than the remaining number of rows in the table, simply because we will be adding these rows in via a click of a button within a `<td>` element.  So, never will that ever happen.  I just need to know how to add in 1 row `<tr>` element in its proper place according to the rowspans, cause, when clicking the `<td>` element before this, it increases the rowspan by 1, so it needs to add in the row also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `button` elements inside your `td` and bind a click event to them.

```
<button class="btn">Add</button>
```

The event triggered to the buttons inside the `td` elements, will find the parent `td` element and retrieve the `rowspan` attribute. Then it will get the parent `tr` element and move to the `rowspan - 1` following sibling `tr` element and will add a `tr` after it.

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var
        $this = $(this),
        $td = $this.parent(),
        rowspan = $td.attr("rowspan") || 1,
        $tr = $td.parent();

    for(var i=1; i<rowspan; ++i)
        $tr = $tr.next();
    $tr.after('<tr><td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td></tr>');
});
```

This is [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jhjrh/2/).

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, just had to switch it so that the incrementing of the rowspan on the `<td>` element was done after this code was performed.  Cheers :)